# what data storage model is used to store articles in wikipedia

Tags: mysql, database, data-structures, storage, wikipedia

Articles in wikipedia get edited. They can grow/shrink/updated etc. What file system/database storage layout etc is used underneath to support it. In database course, I had read a bit on variable length record, but that seemed like more for small strings and not for whole document. Like in file system, files can grow/shrink etc, and I think its done by chaining blocks together. each time, we update a file, not the whole file is rewritten. Perhaps something similar would be done here.

I am looking for specific names,terminologies, may be even how the schema in mysql is defined. (I think wikipedia uses mysql).

Below are links to some writeup on wikipedia architecture, but I am not being able to answer my question from these:

http://swe.web.cs.unibo.it/twiki/pub/WikiFactory/AntonelloDiMuroThesis/Wikipedia-cheapandexplosivescalingwithLAMP.pdf

http://dom.as/uc/workbook2007.pdf

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See:

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Database_layout

Comment: ok, does the **text** table : old_id:(integer 8), old_text(mediumblob),old_flags (tinyblob) contain the text of article? what is mediumblob? sth related to mysql?

Comment: ok, just read on internet what is mediumblob. perhaps this has the clue to my question. This makes me curious though, how mysql internally implements mediumblob? how it handles editing of article somewhere in middle etc..any pointers on it?

Comment: Blobs are binary strings. I'm guessing they're used instead of text fields here and there, due to the potential of having multiple character sets in the database. That way, everyone is (un-)happy. The most important tables, [according to the docs](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Database_layout), are page, revision, pagelinks and text.

Comment: @p2pnode Information about an edit is not stored there, it becomes a new row in the revision and text table. The structure is explained more at http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Page_table . The page table stores info about a page, the revisions store info about the various revisions , or "edits", the actual page text is stored in the text page. The whole page text is stored for each revision, even if it's "an edit in the middle", you use some external diff tool or code to visualize what has been changed/edited between various revisions, that's not something mysql concerns it with.